# Isn't this a math question that should be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

I'm puzzled by how other users are reacting to this question.

[Is it possible to find the number of triangles that can be formed from a list of lengths in better than (n choose 3) time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855682/is-it-possible-to-find-the-number-of-triangles-that-can-be-formed-from-a-list-of)

I commented first indicating that it looks like a math question and not a programming question; however, people are up-voting both the question and the answer.  One answer that's being up-voted has no programming content whatsoever.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Why didn't you vote to close it if you think it's off topic and meriting closure?

Comment: I think the "*in better than O(n choose 3) time*" pull it back into programming territory. Whether that tug is significant I'll leave up to others.

Comment: @Servy -- Because I'm not sure, hence my question here.

Comment: @CubeJockey That would make it a comp sci question, still not a programming question.

Comment: @Servy -- Exactly.  It hasn't got anything to do with problems experienced while writing software or using applications commonly used to write software.

Comment: Hm, perhaps the [Algorithm] tag should be updated to read less broad in scope: "*- Use this tag when your issue is related to algorithm design.*"

Comment: You are in the [algo] tag... where [haskell] seems a walk in the part.

Comment: It seems a good question; its perhaps not entirely about programming in the "there is code" sense of the definition but definitely within the realm of math-oriented programming logic,  it seems useful to many other people and best of all: the SO community already rapidly and successfully provided answers so apparently the target audience is there. At this point I would yank the irrelevant C# tag from it and just let it be. But maybe that would set a bad example, I don't know.

Comment: @Gimby It'd be a good question *if posted on a site where it is on topic*, such as, say, comp sci.  It's *not* a good question when posted on a site where it's off topic.

Comment: @Servy -- While I largely agree (and voted to close the question as you did), I think the rules are vague.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) states that "if your question generally covers…a software algorithm...then you’re in the right place", and the [algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) tag indicates to "use this tag when your issue is related to algorithm design".  I can't find anything else that clarifies it, so I wouldn't say that it's *specifically* off topic, but rather that comp-sci would be a better home for it.

Comment: Seems confusing. Since it can fit any of the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @ManojKumar -- Well, not *any*.  Certainly not [English Language](http://english.stackexchange.com/), [Parenting](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/), or [Buddhism](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/), to name a few.  In fact, it fits in relatively few :)

Comment: @rory.ap - It's not enough for it to be a software algorithm. The help includes: *; **and is** a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development*.

Answer (score 30):

No, this shouldn't be closed! I see no reason at all not to allow language-agnostic algorithm questions here. Heck, they're explicitly allowed by point 2 of the ["Asking"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page in the Help Center:

> ## What topics can I ask about here?
>
> ... if your question generally covers...
>
> - ...
> - **a software algorithm**, or
> - ...
> - ...
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

That's pretty explicit. The fact that [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) exists (and would also be a reasonable place to post this question) does not nullify what the help center says; it's been thoroughly established by now that some questions are on-topic on multiple Stack Exchange sites, and that's fine.

Really, I can't make sense of why anyone would choose to close this. We're talking about a question that:

- Is of a type *explicitly* permitted by the Help Center
- Is well-written, specific, interesting, and (in principle) answerable
- Is the sort of problem a future programmer would come across and Google while programming, looking for an answer on Stack Overflow
- Is thoroughly within the area of expertise of Stack Overflow users (and indeed an answer has already been given)

I've voted to reopen. Closing perfectly good, relevant questions like this is *precisely* what gives Stack Overflow a bad reputation for overly-strict and arbitrary moderation.

Comment: Good answer.  You've certainly convinced me.

Comment: "I can't make sense of why anyone would choose to close this." Because is what sets us aside other related sites. The most important part that somehow everyone ignores is **"and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"** It has to also be something unique to software development. This isn't unique to software development.

Comment: @Braiam how is an algorithm complexity question *not* unique to software development?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I need algorithms to solve my optimization problems for operational research, that means that *any* question I have about my algo is on topic on SO? I am heck sure the answer is no

Comment: @Braiam you're most welcome to ask *any* practical and answerable question about *any* algorithm you want *if* it's well-researched, well-written, clear, not asked before etc.

Comment: For me Stack Overflow is a site **for programmers, by programmers, to ask programing questions**. When I have a practical programming question only then I would ask, otherwise I prefer not asking a question on a site I know is not the *right site*. [New users gets confused enough about this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279661/213575), I prefer not giving more reasons to be confused.

Comment: @Braiam to clarify, which condition (or conditions) out of "practical", "answerable", and "unique to software development" are you claiming the question at hand doesn't meet?

Comment: @MarkAmery  "**unique** to software development".

Comment: @Braiam okay - so what field unrelated to software development would this be relevant to? Is your argument that since abstract algorithm questions could in principle be of interest to pure mathematicians without any concern about software development (though I think that in the real world complexity theory postdates software development and was created to aid in it, rather than being a branch of mathematics that had been around prior to actual software), the uniqueness condition is violated and the question is off-topic? That seems like an overly literal reading of the rules to me, at best.

Comment: @MarkAmery the more literal you read it, the best. It was *meant to be read literally*, as is, otherwise, if it had some profound meaning, it would only serve to cause confusion. Remember, those rules are the most prominent place where new users can figure out whenever their question is ok or not, *being clear and precise in what you mean for those cases is important*.

Comment: @Braiam the problem with the interpretation that you are using here is that it renders all questions off-topic. Any question anyone asks about software development could hypothetically be asked out of idle curiosity by somebody not carrying out software development, hence, the argument would go, nothing is allowed. But that's plainly silly. I don't see the difference here. The fact that academics - some of them not software developers themselves, certainly - have formalized some ways of analyzing software problems doesn't mean that they cease to be software problems.

Comment: @Braiam perhaps our disagreement would be clarified if you explored what the difference is between software algorithm questions in general (explicitly allowed by the help center) and the question discussed here. What kind of questions that "generally cover" an algorithm (to use the help center's words) *are* on-topic, in your mind? If the answer is "none", then I think your interpretation is rather less straightforward and *literal* than mine. If it's not, then what do the on-topic algorithm questions look like, and how do they differ from this case (which seems totally typical to me)?

Comment: How would render all question off topic @MarkAmery? You are doing something that nobody but those in the software development industry are able to answer, you are in the clear. There are at least 4 million of such examples, [my very first question was something no user in its quality of user would do](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6301700). BTW, the help center in the don't ask says ["You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: The ones that include some sort of code and/or the question is about the code, not about the underlying algorithm. For example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24101718/792066).